# Histogram by levels

Tags: r, time, histogram, frequency

My data consists in four time series (here, from A to D), and I want to observe the frequency of a continuous value within each serie, through time.
That is, I would like to have time on the x-axis, with A, B, C, and D, and, for each time range, a vertical histogram.

To be more clear, I would like to obtain something similar to

[image: what I get using this code]:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=values)) + geom_boxplot()
```

but with histograms instead of boxplots.

Here is the data:

```
values  time
0,24    A
0,70    A
0,36    A
0,73    A
0,72    A
0,72    A
0,58    A
0,62    A
0,24    B
0,76    B
0,70    B
0,36    B
0,73    B
0,62    B
0,24    C
0,63    C
0,71    C
0,36    C
0,73    C
0,92    C
0,62    C
0,85    C
0,40    C
0,49    C
0,63    D
0,73    D
0,71    D
0,92    D
0,57    D
0,92    D
0,85    D
```

Comment: Would this work?  `ggplot(data, aes(x=values)) + geom_histogram()
 + facet_wrap(~time)`

Comment: histogram for different times? or do you mean a barplot with mean/sum/count of values by time?

Comment: @Gopala this code gives a matrix of 4 histograms. What I need is these histograms successively on the same x-axis, with the same y-axis (from 0 to 100%)

Comment: You can also try `ggplot(data, aes(x=values)) + geom_histogram(position = 'dodge')`. Problem with histograms on the same scale is that they can overlap and clutter. Box plot example you show, that is not the case.

Comment: A nice way to visualize a distribution is to use a violin plot. Maybe geom_violin() is what you're looking for.

Comment: Here is what I would like (roughly):https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2JaG0Km7pFfdDlqOW9ic3ZQSUk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
    library(ggplot2)
    DF=data.frame(time=rep(LETTERS[1:4],each=100),values=rnorm(400,5,2))
    ggplot(DF, aes(x=values)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~time,ncol=4)+
      coord_flip()+
      theme_classic()
```

Comment: Exactly!
Is there any way to change the number of frequency classes ?

Comment: check ?geom_histogram. You'll see that geom_histogram(bins=5) will do that based on the number you want, and geom_histogram(binwidth=2)  based on the width of the classes you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!